# I want to use market place on my cheap tablet

Tags: google-play-store, 3.0-honeycomb

Alright I'm cheap bought a couple cheap tablets for my kids. We have enjoyed alot of the apps ava on the Market Place but it will not work with the tablets. (Something about "Honey Comb".

My question is there a work around or someway to get the apps I want or upgrade my os so I can get the market place?

Answer (score 5):

Android Market isn't a free service, it requires the tablet to be licensed by Google. Usually the cheap tablets don't have the license, and can't access the Market. There are ways to install it afterwards, but I think that they are usually model specific.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 'rooted' your device, and installed recovery onto it, then you can use a gapps package located here to install the android market onto it:

[gapps Download](http://goo-inside.me/gapps/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an updated OS, you should contact the device manufacturer and ask them about it.  Generally for cheap tablets the installed stock ROM is all you ever get.

Your best bet is to root and unlock your tablet and install a ROM that has Google Apps available for it.  Since you don't list your tablet model, that's the most specific advice on that score I can give.

Failing that, there are lots of third party sites around that you let download the APKs (installation files) for apps independently of the market place.  You can install them so long as you have `Unknown Sources` checked in `Settings->Applications`  You can either visit those sites directly on your tablet or visit them on your PC and transfer the download APKs to your tablet via your home network.  You should be able to install them just by navigating to them in a file explorer and clicking on them ("sideloading").  I like [Android Community](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/download/apps/) myself.

**Caution**: you run a much higher risk of getting malware installed on your device this way.  I would advise installing an anti-malware app like Prey on your device.